# docker compose: network two react apps

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to learn docker-compose networking. I have two react apps that each display a web page at */one* and */two*, respectively. Before trying to network them, each app ran separately without issue using docker-compose and using this setting in the compose files...

```
ports:
    - 3001:3000
```

Now, I need to run them both on the same docker network. So, I created a docker network named *common-network* and added that network reference to the docker-compose file for each app. I also updated the second app compose file to only expose its container port `EXPOSE 3000` (see file at bottom); otherwise if I kept the same port mapping of 3001:3000 for both then there was a host port conflict for 3001.

Using the files below, if I do a `docker-compose up -d --build` for each app, I confirmed that I can ping the other service from either container without issue using `docker exec -it <container> ping <service>`. However, once I navigate in a browser to */one*, if I navigate to */two* I get a blank page.

Am I going about this wrong?

What do I need to do to successfully navigate between them?

first:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  page-one-dev:
    container_name: page-one-dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - DOCKER_CLIENT_TIMEOUT=120
      - COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=120
networks: 
  default: 
    external: 
      name: common-network
```

second:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  page-two-dev:
    container_name: page-two-dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
   # ports:
    #  - 3001:3000
    expose:
      - 3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - DOCKER_CLIENT_TIMEOUT=120
      - COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=120
networks: 
  default: 
    external: 
      name: common-network
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, since you want both apps to be accessible on the same port and host, you need what's called a "reverse proxy".

The most common ones are [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/), [caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) and, particularly interesting in a container environment, [traefik](https://caddyserver.com/).